# Getting error while running a test case in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

here's my test case category_test.rb

```
require "test_helper"

class CategoryTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
  def setup
    @category = Category.new(name: "Sports")
  end

  test "category should be valid" do
   assert @category.valid?
  end
```

This is the error, when I run rails test file. I have also implemented devise.

```
E

Error:
CategoryTest#test_category_should_be_valid:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: RuntimeError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email
    C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.6.3-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:310:in `exec_batch'
    C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.6.3-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:310:in `execute_batch2'
    C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:130:in `block (2 level
s) in execute_batch'
 0.5/lib/active_support/concurrency
/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize
'
```

Why test case is failing each time I run rails test?

Comment: The error is obviously in database constraint on `users` table: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: RuntimeError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email`. Somewhere in the code you create two users with same email. Most likely in fixtures/fabrics. Be sure your test suite start on fresh database and database tables are empty when tests finished.

Comment: I deleted all users , still getting same error

Comment: Have you deleted the users from your test database ? Do you have a tool to delete on the database or have you done a `rails c` and deleted from console ? Because you many need to start your console in test environment `rails c -e test`

Comment: Basically you need to clean up your test database between each test..

Comment: Well, it's easy to find out. Just catch all errors and raise it in the test where it fails. Then in the catch, log out all users in DB. As the other guys says it's most likely due to a config error where not all users are wiped after each test. Or, you can just avoid the whole thing by using Faker.

Answer (score -1):

but since you haven't provided additional information,
is it possible that you also have fixtures set up and that is what produces the error. Sometimes if you use rails g model or scaffold or anything it will also create fixtures for you but the values are pretty generic something like:

```yaml
 # test/fixtures.categories.yml
 one:
  name: My String

two:
  name: My String
```

And this is where the unique constraint fails.
I am also sorry if not helpful, it's just something that happens to me from time to time.

Comment: Question Is not clear.